# float's not returing to position after mobile view end

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my menu when I am in mobile view the it does not float which is correct.

Problem being when I come out of the mobile view my class "menu-right" floats left until I reload my page.

Is it possible so when it comes out of mobile view that the "menu-right" class will automatically go to the float right with out me reloading page.

I am not sure if it's to do with the css or my java script.

Live Code Example: http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/GgLjmL

Live Code Full View: http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/full/GgLjmL/

**Java Script**

```
var ww = document.body.clientWidth;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu li a").each(function() {
        if ($(this).next().length > 0) {
            $(this).addClass("parent");
        };
    })

    $(".menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass("menu-button");
        $("#menu").toggle();
    });
    adjustMenu();
})

$(window).bind('resize orientationchange', function() {
    ww = document.body.clientWidth;
    adjustMenu();
});

var adjustMenu = function() {
    if (ww < 768) {
        $(".menu-toggle").css("display", "inline-block");
        if (!$(".menu-toggle").hasClass("menu-button")) {
            $("#menu").hide();
        } else {
            $("#menu").show();
        }
        $("#menu li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
        $("#menu li a.parent").unbind('hover').bind('hover', function(e) {
            // must be attached to anchor element to prevent bubbling
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent("li").toggleClass("hover");
        });

        $(".menu-right").removeClass("menu-right");
    } 
    else if (ww >= 768) {
        $(".menu-toggle").css("display", "none");
        $("#menu").show();
        $("#menu li").removeClass("hover");
        $("#menu li a").unbind('hover');
        $("#menu li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
            // must be attached to li so that mouseleave is not triggered when hover over submenu
            $(this).toggleClass('hover');
        });
        $(".menu-right").addClass("menu-right");
    }
}
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
}

#content {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.default-theme {
    background-color: #fafafa !important;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f2f2f2) !important;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#f2f2f2)) !important;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f2f2f2) !important;
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f2f2f2) !important;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #f2f2f2) !important;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#fff2f2f2', GradientType=0);
    *zoom: 1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065) !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065) !important;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065) !important;
}

body, 
#menu, 
ul, 
li, 
a  {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

a, 
a:visited {
    color: #003366;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#header .div1 {
    height: 56px;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    background: url('../img/header.png') repeat-x;
    min-width: 900px;
}
#header .div2 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 18px 0px 0px 0px;
    float: left;
}
#header .div3 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
    float: right;
}
#header .div2 span {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.container-menu {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu-right {
  float:right !important;
}

.menu-toggle {
    display:  none;
}

#menu {
    list-style: none;
    *zoom: 1;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    background: rgba(19,19,19,1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,19,19,1) 0%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 0%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 0%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 0%, rgba(44,44,44,1) 2%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 4%, rgba(61,61,61,1) 27%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(19,19,19,1)), color-stop(0%, rgba(17,17,17,1)), color-stop(0%, rgba(102,102,102,1)), color-stop(0%, rgba(43,43,43,1)), color-stop(2%, rgba(44,44,44,1)), color-stop(4%, rgba(71,71,71,1)), color-stop(27%, rgba(61,61,61,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(28,28,28,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,19,19,1) 0%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 0%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 0%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 0%, rgba(44,44,44,1) 2%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 4%, rgba(61,61,61,1) 27%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,19,19,1) 0%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 0%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 0%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 0%, rgba(44,44,44,1) 2%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 4%, rgba(61,61,61,1) 27%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,19,19,1) 0%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 0%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 0%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 0%, rgba(44,44,44,1) 2%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 4%, rgba(61,61,61,1) 27%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(19,19,19,1) 0%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 0%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 0%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 0%, rgba(44,44,44,1) 2%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 4%, rgba(61,61,61,1) 27%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#131313', endColorstr='#1c1c1c', GradientType=0 );
}

#menu:before,
#menu:after {
    content: " "; 
    display: table; 
}

#menu:after {
    clear: both;
}

#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
}

#menu a {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none
}

#menu li {
    position: relative;
}

#menu > li {
    float: left;
}

#menu > li > a {
    display: block;
}

#menu li  ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}

#menu > li.hover > ul {
    left: 0;
}
#menu li li.hover ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

#menu ul .top {
    background-image: url('../img/arrow-right.png'); 
    background-position: 95% center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#menu li li a {
    display: block;
    background: #000000; /* A grey background */
    opacity: 0.7; /* 80% opacity */
    position: relative;
    z-index:100;
    width: 147px;
} 

#menu li li li a {
    background: #000000; /* A grey background */
    opacity: 0.7; /* 80% opacity */
    z-index:200;
}

#menu li li li a:hover,
#menu li li a:hover {
    margin: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #BD4C14;
    background-color: #391706;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #menu-header {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    background: rgba(19,19,19,1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,19,19,1) 0%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 0%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 0%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 0%, rgba(44,44,44,1) 2%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 4%, rgba(61,61,61,1) 27%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(19,19,19,1)), color-stop(0%, rgba(17,17,17,1)), color-stop(0%, rgba(102,102,102,1)), color-stop(0%, rgba(43,43,43,1)), color-stop(2%, rgba(44,44,44,1)), color-stop(4%, rgba(71,71,71,1)), color-stop(27%, rgba(61,61,61,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(28,28,28,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,19,19,1) 0%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 0%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 0%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 0%, rgba(44,44,44,1) 2%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 4%, rgba(61,61,61,1) 27%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,19,19,1) 0%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 0%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 0%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 0%, rgba(44,44,44,1) 2%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 4%, rgba(61,61,61,1) 27%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,19,19,1) 0%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 0%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 0%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 0%, rgba(44,44,44,1) 2%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 4%, rgba(61,61,61,1) 27%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(19,19,19,1) 0%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 0%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 0%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 0%, rgba(44,44,44,1) 2%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 4%, rgba(61,61,61,1) 27%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#131313', endColorstr='#1c1c1c', GradientType=0 );
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    }

    #menu-header button {
        color: #FFF;
        border-color: 1px solid #FFF !important;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    #menu {
        background: #000000 !important;
        clear: both;
    }

    #menu > li {
        float: none;
    }

    #menu li li a {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #menu ul {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #menu > li.hover > ul , #menu li li.hover ul {
        position: static;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-menu">
<div id="menu-header">
    <button type="button" class="menu-toggle btn btn-primary">
        Menu
    </button>
</div>
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Catalog</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Categories</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Categories</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Extensions</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Modules</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sales</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="top">Customers</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Customers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Customer Group</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">System</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Setting</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="top">Design</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Layouts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Banners</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="top">Users</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">User</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">User Group</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-right"><a href="">Logout</a></li>
    <li class="menu-right"><a href="">Website Front</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a media screen like:

@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {}

and reset all the style changed with:

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {}

```css
@media (min-width: 769px) {
 h1 {color: red;}
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
 h1 {color: green;}
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Color</h1>

<script>
 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem is that when you resize the screen like the size of a mobile and then you come back to the normal size it doesen't work correctly?

It's because when you "go" to a size of <768px the css changes. So you have to add the css for the size >768.

Comment: Tried it no luck not sure what done wrong. You have any example?

Comment: It could be?
When you go to a small screen the color change and then when you go to big you have to reset the attribute like I did in my code.

Comment: So.. when have to add this: @media (min-width: 769px) {
 .menu-right {
  float: right !important;
}
}
And then it works, I think.